# Pass or passed, which one is more appropriate in the scenario

Tags: grammar

If i cleared the exam, what would the teacher say while addressing me "you are pass" or " you are passed "

Comment: *You have passed the test* or *You passed the test*.

Comment: He wouldn't say either. He'd say "you passed". For future questions, consider our sister site dedicated to helping people learn English as a foreign language, [ELL.se].

Comment: You can say "You passed" or "You have passed." 
You could say "You cleared," but it is less common.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the teacher would say one of two things:

***"You passed."*** 
This is an example of the simple past tense and is used when an action has been started and completed in the past. You passed the moment your exam had been graded, and personally, I hear this said more often.

OR

***"You have passed."***
This is an example of the perfect present tense: An action completed in the past but has a strong emphasis on its effect in the present!

Answer (score -2):

You "passed" the exam. To pass any kind of test or exam is to meet or exceed the minimum requirements.